# Android Notification not start activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem. 
When I click on a notification will be canceled but will not open the activity. 
This is the code:

**GcmIntentService.java**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                con)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(
                        Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE
                                | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(msg);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(con, Notification.class);

        resultIntent.putExtra("message", msg);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(con);

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Home.class);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

**EDIT**:

I solved with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);    
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // hide the notification after its selected
            noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

And now my notification work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:(you need to specify Activity launch intent, which you should put into pending intent)

please read the following guide to create working notifications from scratch: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

```
    // Intent that will launch activity
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, MainFragmentFaceActivity.class);

    // Creates the PendingIntent
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, notifyIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Puts the PendingIntent into the notification builder
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notifyManager.notify(R.id.notification_move, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: @ruben Did you try API Demos project?

Comment: How? Create a new notification project end linked as library?

Comment: No, please read my post again, i updated it. You should read the whole section to understand well what and how you should do. There are samples and examples.